# Why do i see empty files in Intent.ACTION_PICK?

Tags: java, android

When i start new intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_LOAD_MAIN_IMAGE);
```

I see empty files that i deleted before using this method:

```
public static void DeleteRecursive(DocumentFile fileOrDirectory) {
    if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
        for (DocumentFile child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {
            DeleteRecursive(child);
        }
    }
    fileOrDirectory.delete();
}
```

I can't see them in normal file manager, only in intent. Files dissapear when i reboot my phone.
Is this normal or should i remove files another way? Thank you.

Comment: "Is this normal" -- more or less. `MediaStore` still thinks that they are there, until it notices that they are gone. I am not certain if there is a reliable way to tell `MediaStore` to re-index and remove the deleted items. You can tell the `MediaStore` about *new* or *updated* items via `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()`.

Comment: Either this or you can force a scan of the file via Broadcast (but this isn't such good resource-wise when deleting many files):
`Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);`
`scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));`
`sendBroadcast(scanIntent);`

Comment: @CommonsWare Got it, thanks.

Comment: @Ch4t4r So i should do this for each file, right? Maybe i should do this in AsyncTask with another file operations. Thank you.